# Routong with Vue does not open the corresponding page (not work at all)

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, routes

js and I am facing a problem with routing.  vue-router@4.2.5, vue version 3.5.5. I also use springboot for the back end. I use 2 plugins in pom.xml to make both backend and frontend works in the same port (in localhost). But routing does not work when I type a url I have set up Whitelabel Error Page appeared.

I create a button in App.vue and when press it should go to a new page RegistrationForm.vue. Instead WhitePageError.

router.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import RegistrationForm from './components/RegistrationForm.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/omg/home',
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    component: HelloWorld,
  },
  {
    path: '/omg/registration',
    name: 'RegistrationForm',
    component: RegistrationForm,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router'; // Import your router configuration

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router); // Use the router

app.mount('#app');
```

vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/omg': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Welcome to my App</h1>
    <button @click="goToRegistration">Go to Registration</button>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    goToRegistration() {
      this.$router.push('omg/registration');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.omgWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>gymWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <!--Java Version-->
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <node.version>v17.7.1</node.version>
        <npm.version>8.5.2</npm.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web for REST APIs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Data JPA for JPA support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- downloads/installs Node and NPM locally for your project, and runs npm install and npm build to build your
            Vue application. The output for this build is stored in the /src/frontend/dist directory.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.6</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <!--handles the copying of project resources to the output directory. You will need to copy everything from the
            src/frontend/dist directory to the target/classes/static directory.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Copy Vue frontend into Spring Boot target static folder</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/frontend/dist</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: "both backend and frontend works in the same port" ... why?  likely the routing confusion stems from you doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You define the `devServer` to proxy requests from `/omg` path to your localhost:8080 backend but you also defined your routes to be starting with `/omg` path with history being `createWebHistory` so with app pages not being in `/#/omg` but more `/omg` form (doc [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode))

In this situation, I'm pretty sure that your router send the request to the SpringBoot webapp rather than in your real webpage.

Maybe you could change this proxy to proxy only specific subpath like `/omg/rest` and see if it works